# I have a "Call to Indefined function " PHP error

Tags: php

I get a Fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function addProject() in C:\wamp64\www\VD\Test\controller\ControllerIntegration.php on line 12

while my require is OK in my file.

```
public function addProjectController($projectName) {
    $project = new Integration();

    $affectedLines = addProject($projectName);


    if ($affectedLines === false) {
        throw new Exception('Impossible d\'ajouter le projet !                                  ');     
    }
    else
    {
        header('location : index.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: If its a member of your class, then probably you need `$this->addProject()`

Comment: Well, where do you define the function?

Comment: In an other file in model

Comment: A public method, so now i have this "Call to undefined method ControllerIntegration::addProject()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that `addProject()` is a model function, so create object of the model and then call it.

```
$modelObj = new <Model name>(<pass parameters if any required>);
$affectedLines = $modelObj->addProject($projectName);
```

Note:- if `addProject` is static function of your model then directly called it like below:

```
$affectedLines = <Model name>::addProject($projectName);
```

A sample example:-

```
$userObj = new User();
$affectedLines = $userObj->addProject($projectName);
//or
$affectedLines = User::addProject($projectName); // if addProject() is static method
```